# Loops with unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

This is a color guessing game I'm working on. Basically it allows users to select a color out of six, and output correct if the color is the same as mentioned in the title or output try again if the color is wrong. When I try the first game, everything seems fine but when I select play again and select the colors again, an unexpected recursion occurs and I don't know where's the problem. Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    "use strict";
    let header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
    let titleColor = document.getElementById("title_color");
    let nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
    let newColors = document.getElementById("new_colors");
    let prompt = document.getElementById("prompt");
    let easy = document.getElementById("easy");
    let hard = document.getElementById("hard");
    let active = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
    let colors = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=color]");
    const initialize = () => {
        let t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            colors[i].style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
        }
        titleColor.innerHTML = colors[t].style.backgroundColor;
        addingEventHandlers(t);
    }
    const addingEventHandlers = t => {
        for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            colors[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log(i);
                if (t === i) {
                    header.style.backgroundColor = colors[t].style.backgroundColor;
                    for (let j = 0; j < nav.children.length; j++) {
                        if (nav.children[j] === active) {
                            nav.children[j].style.color = "rgb(FF, FF, FF)";
                            nav.children[j].style.backgroundColor = colors[t].style.backgroundColor;
                        } else {
                            nav.children[j].style.color = colors[t].style.backgroundColor;
                            nav.children[j].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(FF, FF, FF)";
                        }
                    }
                    for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
                        colors[j].style.backgroundColor = colors[t].style.backgroundColor;
                    }
                    prompt.innerHTML = "Correct";
                    newColors.innerHTML = "Play Again";
                    newColors.addEventListener("click", () => initialize())
                } else {
                    console.log(i);
                    colors[i].style.transitionProperty = "background-color";
                    colors[i].style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                    colors[i].style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-in-out";
                    colors[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                    prompt.innerHTML = "Try Again";
                    newColors.innerHTML = "New Colors";
                    newColors.addEventListener("click", () => initialize())
                }
            })
        }
    }
    initialize();
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    color: white;
    background-color: navy;
    margin: 0;
}
header>h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}
header>h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: white;
    color: navy;
    position: relative;
    height: 38px;
}
nav>button {
    background-color: white;
    color: navy;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
} 
#new_colors {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
}
#easy {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62%;
}
#hard {
    position: absolute;
    left: 72%;
}
nav>button:not(.active):hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}
button.active {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
#container {
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 792px;
}
[id^=color] {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
[id^=color]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#color1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
#color2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}
#color3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}
#color4 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
#color5 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
#color6 {
    grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="color guessing game">
        <meta name="description" content="color guessing game">
        <meta name="author" content="Nick">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="color_guessing.css">
        <script src="color_guessing.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h3>The Great</h3>
            <h1 id="title_color"></h1>
            <h3>Guessing Game</h3>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <button id="new_colors">New Colors</button>
            <button id="prompt"></button>
            <button id="easy" >Easy</button>
            <button id="hard" class="active">Hard</button>
        </nav>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="color1"></div>
            <div id="color2"></div>
            <div id="color3"></div>
            <div id="color4"></div>
            <div id="color5"></div>
            <div id="color6"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you specify the problem further than "an unexpected recursion occurs"?  What is this 'unexpected recursion'? Is there an error logged in the console (and does it say what line triggers the issue?) If it's not a syntax error but a logic error, what unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I console.log the variable i as i want to know what's going on with the loops. I console.log twice so it shows the i variable twice when the color is wrong and once when the color is correct. But when I click "play again" and select the colors again, there are six console.logs which means the loop has looped three times. I expect the user's chosen color will be disappeared when wrong, and all the colors become the correct color when correct. I get the result the first game, but not from the second one

Comment: Every time you call `initialize()` you add yet another `click`-listener to the same DOM nodes. So in the 3rd round, you have 3 contradicting click-listener on ever color node.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Thomas said in the comments you need to check if there is an event already and add an event listener if there is none.

```
if (!colors[i].onclick) {
    // your add event listener code goes here
}
```

Comment: First, `colors[i].onclick` doesn't detect/reflect event listener added with `colors[i].addEventListener("click", ...)`. Second, using `onclick` instead of `addEventListener` would be one way to solve the problem, as it would overwrite the old event listener instead of adding a second, third, nth one.

Answer (score 0):

You call `addingEventHandlers` from within `initialise`. This means that when `initialise` is called again (like when you start a new game) you will call `addEventListener` on the same element a *second* time, meaning you will call a handler twice when the event occurs. And this only gets worse as you call `initialise` again and again.

So move the call to `addingEventHandlers` outside of the `initialise` function body, so that it only gets called on page load, and then no more.